# Create Azure VM Start/Stop solution on weekends without automation runbook

Tags: azure-virtual-machine

As a user,

I want to implement the tags in the repo

so that the non prod servers can be shutdown in weekday nights and weekends

Hi

is that possible to creating stop and start Auto shutdown to the AZURE Virtual Machines in weekends, without Automation runtime is that possible to start and stop the VM, using script

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can schedule the virtual machine according to the requirement in off hours.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-solution-vm-management

Check the procedure mentioned in the above documentation from Microsoft.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/start-azvm?view=azps-7.5.0 -> This link is to start the virtual machine

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/stop-azvm?view=azps-7.5.0 -> This link is to stop the virtual machine.